# Graffiti CMS breaks on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, url-routing, iis-7.5, graffiticms

I have 5 web sites all running Graffiti CMS. One of the sites stopped working such that basically when any page other than the home page is accessed, I get a 404 Not Found from IIS. All the sites are running identical (well, nearly identical) code and this broken site previously worked then suddenly stopped (with no code changes).

The error message from the broken site suggests it is running IIS 7.5 - I suspect that the hosting provider may have upgraded the web server and forgotten to tell me. The 4 working sites are all on a different IP address on a server that I think is still running IIS 7.0.

the web.config files are the same in each case, except for DB connection string.

Could anyone venture a guess at why IIS 7.5 would break URL routing like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: My web server's configuration had been changed, the application pool was in 'classic' mode and needed to be changed to 'integrated pipeline'.